# How find with Sequelize results where column A > column B + column C

Tags: sequelize.js

DB table with 3 columns - `A int`, `B int`, `C int`

**My problem is:** How to find with sequelize results where `A > B + C`

```
const countTasks = await Tasks.count({
    where: {
        A: {
            [Op.gt]: B + C // ???
        },
    },
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: I put an basic answer. If you can improve your question with a minimal reproducible example, your help will come faster and better. See more in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE A > B+C;
```